# comparing string to time

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get total figures from a report to sql.  I only want this to happen if a row is newer than the last to go into sql so I am adding a date and time that is tagged on the report:

e.g.

```
141480128217,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g3t3,19/01/2013 02:58pm
182483629803,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g3t3,19/01/2013 03:01pm
108484044725,WRONG_PERFORMANCE,g3t1,19/01/2013 03:10pm
```

so if I ran this already and the last row added previously was the one at 03:01pm so the total 'WRONG_PERFORMANCE' was 2 but running it again I want it to be 3 but I'm doubling up with each update so the first would be 2 and the second would be 5 and even if there is no new row it would still be 8 next update (5 + 3) and so on.  to avoid this I want to make sure that the date in the report is newer than the last update from sql (I would be adding the date from each row and replacing the date from the previous so that the last one to be added will be the date in sql) but as it is a string it doesn't compare correctly.  How would I go about doing this?  I have tried a few different methods but have gotten nowhere.

**EDIT**
I have tried the following:

```
$newDate = date("d/m/y/ h:i:s", strtotime("19/01/2013 01:42pm"));
```

And got the result:

```
01/01/70/ 12:00:00
```

I tried switching the day and month like so:

```
$newDate = date("d/m/y h:i:s", strtotime("01/19/2013 01:42pm"));
```

and got the following:

```
19/01/13 01:42:00
```

so how do I get this to work with the report as it is?!?

***RESULT***

```
$date = str_replace("/", "-", "19/01/2013 01:42pm");
$newDate = date("d/m/y h:i:s", strtotime("$date"));
echo $newDate;
```

returned the correct date format!

Comment: thanks for fixing that KPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the date to YYYY-MM-DD format (include the time if you want), then the dates can be sorted numerically.  Then your first (or last, depending on how you sort it) record will be the newest.

Edit:

str_replace fixed your problem because to quote php.net:

"Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed."

Thus, by making your separator into a -, you made php look for a d-m-y date rather than a m/d/y date.

Comment: Also, if that approach doesn't do what you want, try using sql's date functions.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: when I convert the dates I keep getting wildly incorrect dates or nothing at all.  What way would you suggest to change the format?

Comment: strtotime() and date() functions (used together) in php should be able to convert things for you nicely.  SQL has some date functions too, but I haven't used those as much.

Comment: Php expects that if you use /s to separate the three values that it will be in the m/d/y format.  If you use the separator '.' or '-' it should interpret the date in the European style.  So try doing a str_replace on your slashes to make them into periods or dashes before sending it off to the strtotime function.

Comment: Great, I used str_replace prior to the original code and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @njk Thank you for the heads up. I knew there was a reason I didn't use that website anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string as it is to a datetime and use that to compare dates.  *However*, your dates are in D/M/Y format, and your server is quite possibly set to interpret dates as M/D/Y, and there's no 19th month.  :)

If so, try [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) DMY.